# Switch Window Manager with Ubuntu Plymouth splash screen

Tags: window-manager, plymouth

I compiled [DWM](https://dwm.suckless.org/) on my Ubuntu system.

Normally when I switch WM I can do it with Plymouth Ubuntu splash screen with a drop down menu.

The issue is I don't see it in the list and I don't know how to add it.

I try to find where Ubuntu gets its list of WMs but to no avail.

I know I could install [DWM](https://dwm.suckless.org/) with apt package manager but I want to make modifications to the source code.

I know some will say to just use [choosewm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/choosewm.1.html) to swith... I tried and it does not work. It just sends an error saying that another WM is running.

I also tried to just kill the process of my WM (I am using i3wm). But all it does is send me to the splash (login page) screen.

So can I add the my custom compiled [DWM](https://dwm.suckless.org/) to the drop down menu in the splash screen (plymouth) or is there a way to get Ubuntu to stop complaining about switching WM with [choosewm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/choosewm.1.html)?

Details: 
Release 18.04